# Date time in Linux bash

Tags: date, time

I am trying to display a date time in the form of

07/08/2013 16:52:13

by using command in bash script:

```
dt=`date '+%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S'`
```

which variable is used to populate a CSV file.

The only char accepted is "_" (underscore) or "-" between date and time, output is

07/08/2013_16:52:13

How can I get a space in between date and time?
I tried almost (I hope) everything.

Comment: “_” and “-” are the only characters accepted by _who_? What stops you replacing the “_” with “ ” in `date`'s format string?

Comment: Nothing prevents the inclusion of the " " in the command, they just don't appear in the output.  Try date +"%b %e" and you will get "Sep 4" (one space) for today, not the desired 2.  I'm using it in a script and my solution is to do the operation in 3 steps (I actually combine them into one line of code but you get the idea).

Comment: With all due respect, how did this question get 20 votes?  And how did it get into the Reopen Queue?

Answer (score 112):

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
echo "$dt"
```

Guess the problem is in 'echoing' to the csv.

Comment: if you need milliseconds, use `date '+%F %T.%3N'`.
if you need microseconds, use `date '+%F %T.%6N'`.
if you need nanoseconds, use `date '+%F %T.%N'`.
`%F` is for date, it gives `YYYY-MM-DD`,
you can use `%D` instead to get `MM-DD-YYYY`,
`%T` is for time, `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: `echo $dt` is also ok